# How to create HTML+jScript Scroll Triggered Box

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have a blog at Blogger.com and I want to add a Scroll Triggered Box like Dreamgrow or Qoate Scroll Triggered Box of Wordpress. I referred [Scroll Triggered Box with jQuery](http://dannyvankooten.com/189/scroll-triggered-box-with-jquery/). I have created a HTML file and testing it but this is not working for me. May be I have mistaken somewhere. My coding is

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Scroll Triggered Box With jQuery</title>

<style type="text/css">
.Comments
{
font:georgia;
display:none;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var y = $(window).scrollTop();
            var c = $('#comments').offset();
            if (y > (c.top - $(window).height())) {
                $('#the_box').fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                $('#the_box').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
<!--My long post here-->
</div>

<div class="Comments" id="the_box">
This is the DIV that triggers I scroll down to Comments</br>
This is the DIV that triggers I scroll down to Comments</br>
This is the DIV that triggers I scroll down to Comments</br>
This is the DIV that triggers I scroll down to Comments</br>
This is the DIV that triggers I scroll down to Comments</br>
This is the DIV that triggers I scroll down to Comments
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am little weak in jScript. I don't know how jScript works.

**How can I resolve my issue and get this working in my Blogger.com blog?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can tell your code is haywire.

```
  var a =$(window).height();
  var num = c-y;
 if (y > num){
   do your function
    }else{
  do whatever
    }
```

Comment: Didn't get what is haywire......I dnt know jScript. Can you provide me the ready code and steps how to use it or tutorial where I can learn this topic? plz

Comment: the code i wrote works just add the rest of the variables and wrap them in a script tag. what I posted will not show the box until the client's scroll height is greater than the offset of the div - the window height. I am actually at work now when I get home in a few ill throw it on a demo page for you .

Comment: http://seekrr.com/scrollbox/               it works just scroll up and down, please accept my answer, thank you